# How to resolve Sweet32 vulnerability on Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, security, tomcat, ssl, encryption

I am having some trouble getting rid of a server vulnerability. The Sweet32 vulnerability deals with medium strength cipher suites on my web server. The scanner output reads as follows, "The remote host supports the use of SSL ciphers that offer medium strength encryption. Nessus regards medium strength as any encryption that uses key lengths at least 64 bits and less than 112 bits, or else that uses the 3DES encryption suite."

The following medium strength ciphers were found on the server:

```
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA;  
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA;  
DES-CBC3-SHA
```

I tried editing the *server.xml* file for Apache Tomcat. There is a SSL connector portion of the *server.xml* file that I have been editing. It reads as follows, but the vulnerability is still getting flagged. I've also played around with disabling certain ciphers suits in the registry, such as 3DES. Any ideas on how to fix this vulnerability would be so helpful.

```
     <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
     clientAuth="false" 
     port="443"
     scheme="https"  
     minSpareThreads="5" 
     enableLookups="true" 
     acceptCount="100" 
     maxThreads="200"         
     secure="true" 
     SSLEnabled="true"
     keystoreFile="**********" 
     keystorePass="*********"
     sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
     algorithm="IbmX509"
     compression="on" 
     noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
     compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/plain,text        /javascript,application/javascript,application/x-javascript"
 SSLCipherSuite="TLS_EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!3DES:!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Ciphers you listed from the `server.xml` file should fix this.

Like this:

```
SSLCipherSuite="TLS_EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!3DES"
```